# Fastest way to row bind dataframe within for loop in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am trying to find the quickest and most effective way to produce a table using a for loop (or map in purrrr) in R.

I have 15,881 values which I am trying to loop over, for this example assume the values are the numbers 1 to 15,881 incremented by 1, which is this variable:

```
values <- c(1:15881)
```

I am then trying to filter an existing dataframe where a column matches a value and then perform some data cleaning process - the output of this a **single dataframe**, for clarity my process is the following:

Assume in this situation that I have chosen a single value from the values object e.g. `value = values[1]`

So then for a single value I have the following:

```
  df <- df_to_filter %>%
    filter(code == value) %>%
    group_by(code, country) %>%
    group_split() %>%
    purrr::map_dfr(some_other_function) %>%
    filter(!is.na(country))
```

The above code works perfectly fine when I run it for a single value. The output is a desired dataframe. This process takes around 0.7 seconds for a single value.

However, I am trying to append the results of this output to an empty dataframe for each and every single value found in the variable **values**

So far I have tried the following:

## For Loop approach

```
# empty dataframe  to append values to 
empty_df <- tibble()

for (value in values){

  df <- df_to_filter %>%
    filter(code == value) %>%
    group_by(code, country) %>%
    group_split() %>%
    purrr::map_dfr(some_other_function) %>%
    filter(!is.na(country))

 empty_df <- bind_rows(empty_df, df)

}
```

However the above is extremely slow - I did a quick calculation and it would take around 186 minutes `((0.7 seconds per table x 15,881)/60 - seconds in a minute = around 185.7 minutes)` - which is a huge amount of time to process just a dataframe.

Is there a quicker way to speed up the above process instead of a for loop? I can't think of any way to improve the fundamentals of the above code as it does the job well and 0.7 seconds to produce a single table seems fast to me but 15,881 tables is obviously going to take a long time.

I tried using the `purrr` package along with `data.table` but the furthest I got was this:

```
combine_dfs <- function(value){

    df <- df_to_filter %>%
    filter(code == value) %>%
    group_by(code, country) %>%
    group_split() %>%
    purrr::map_dfr(some_other_function) %>%
    filter(!is.na(country))

   df <- data.table(df) 

   rbindlist(list(df, empty_df))

}
```

Then running with `map_df` is this:

```
map_df(values, ~combine_dfs(.))
```

However, even the above is extremely slow and seems to take around the same time!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be much better if you could share a reproducible piece of that existing data frame.

Comment: You really need to provide an reproducible example firstly. Otherwise we can't provide a complete solution and have nothing to compare with your desired  result.

Comment: Could you add some data on your answer?

Comment: The fastest way to rbind frames table in a `for` loop is ... **don't**. This breaks the 2nd Circle of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), titled *"Growing Objects"*. Realize that each time you do this, the data is perfectly duplicated in memory before the new object is created and the old is garbage collected (eventually). This means that if you have 1M rows and want to `rbind` another 10 rows, then you will have 2M+ rows in memory at some point in time. *Don't do this.*

Answer (score 0):

Row binding dataframe in a loop is inefficient irrespective of which library you use.

You have not provided any example data but I think for your case this should work the same.

```
library(dplyr)

df_to_filter %>%
  group_split(code, country) %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(some_other_function) %>%
  filter(!is.na(country)) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hi Could you explain to me how this differs? I understand you are no longer using the for loop - but does the `-> result` send it to a new dataframe? In addition is there any benefit for this speeding up the code I can't see any as it seems to be the same code?

Comment: Yes, `-> result` adds it to a new dataframe called result. In your code `empty_df <- bind_rows(empty_df, df)` or `rbindlist(list(df, empty_df))` is going to completely slow down the process which my code avoids. Also, as everybody has already said it would really be useful if you provided an example to compare our answers.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide an reproducible example firstly. Otherwise we can't provide a complete solution and have nothing to compare the result.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_to_filter)[code %in% values, by = .(code, country)] %>%
group_split(code, country) %>%
purrr::map_dfr(some_other_function) %>%
  filter(!is.na(country))
```